# Woocommerce custom checkout field not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added the following to the functions.php It displays the checkout page fine and all of the typical fields but it does not add the new field or even a little text. I'm using the unaltered storefront theme and no special plugins.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');
    function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
        
        echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('My Field').'</h3>';
                    
        woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array( 
            'type'          => 'text', 
            'class'         => array('my-field-class orm-row-wide'), 
            'label'         => __('Fill in this field'), 
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter a number'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));
        
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Any ideas as to why this field is not showing? Everything I've seen indicates it should work. I've also confirmed the function is loaded.

Comment: You need to replace checkout blocks with classic checkout(shortcode)

Answer (score 1):

you are probably using the blocks checkout, delete it and replace it with the shortcode one.

it worked for me.